# Group a number of datas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS number_plays, id
FROM table
WHERE date_play >= '2017-08-27 00:00:00' AND date_play <= '2017-08-27 23:59:59'
GROUP BY id, date_play
HAVING number_plays > 1
ORDER BY number_plays DESC
```

And the result is comes out to be something like:

```
number_plays                id
20                          15
40                          15
32                          18
20                          15
```

Is it possible to group this result by number of plays? To end up something like:

```
iterations                 number_plays          id
2                          20                    15
1                          40                    15
1                          32                    18
```

Can I get some help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things - First, if you specify a column inside the `GROUP BY` clause, try specifying it inside the `SELECT` as well. Only MySQL allows this, and I find it wrong and can raise errors/ output wrong data and you won't understand why.

Second, just wrap your query with another query, and add the number_plays to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT count(*) as iterations,t.number_plays,t.id
FROM(
    SELECT  id,date_play,COUNT(id) AS number_plays,
    FROM table
    WHERE date_play >= '2017-08-27 00:00:00' 
      AND date_play <= '2017-08-27 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY id, date_play
    HAVING number_plays > 1
    ORDER BY number_plays DESC) t
GROUP BY t.number_plays,t.id
```